# Dynamic concatenating to a vector in matlab

Tags: matlab

Hello I'm trying to perform cross validation using matlab. In each fold i should have a 10x1 vector and I want to concate these vector.

At the end all_scores and all_labels must be 100x1 size but what I'm getting is 1000x1. Anyone know what is the problem in the following code?

```
load iris.dat;
data=iris;
data( data(:,5)==3,:) = [];
labels=data(:,5);



indices = crossvalind('kfold',labels,10);

all_scores = [];
all_labels = [];
for i = 1:10
test = (indices==i);
train = ~test;
[IDX,scores] = knnsearch(train,test);
y =train(IDX);
all_scores = [all_scores; scores];
display(all_scores);
all_labels = [all_labels; y];
display(all_labels);
end
```

Comment: Did you verify `y` is of size `[10 1]`? What is displayed?

Comment: `test` and `train` are both 100x1 logical vectors at each iteration of the loop, and therefore so is `scores` and `y`, which is why `all_scores` and `all_labels` are growing by 100 each time. Prehaps you want `test=find(indices==i)` and `train=find(indices~=i)` instead?

Comment: Thank you so much. it worked.